# asp How to do a foreach loop of controls on the child page that you're currently on

Tags: asp.net

I'm simply trying to change all my RadTextBox borders to black.  i'm sure the structure of my foreach loop is right, however i'm not able to find any RadTextBoxes.

I have a masterpage called master.Page and a childpage inheriting that page called child.aspx.

There is 10 radtextboxes on child.aspx, but i'm unable to find any, i've tried.....

```
foreach (var control in this.Controls.OfType<RadTextBox>())
    {
        control.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    }
    foreach (var control in this.Page.Controls.OfType<RadTextBox>())
    {
        control.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```

}

Comment: Man.. this you are doing is not recommended. Your RadTextBox can be at any level of the Control hierarchy, you would need to loop the controls recursively. A much nicer approach would be to extend RadTextBox and set the BorderColor according to your logic.

Comment: Huh?  I think you're completely over complicating this.  The controls are located directly on child.aspx...

Comment: Ok, then in what event of the life cycle are you doing this?

Comment: You should be able to locate the control in this phase of the life cycle. Did you put a breakpoint in the line before your *foreach* and checked what controls appear in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned that you're using MasterPages. You''ll find the controls which are on top of your child aspx pages from master not via `this.Controls` but  via `contentPlaceHolder1.Controls` since that is the `NamingContainer`.

If you would have other textboxes in child controls like `FormView` or `GridView` you woudn't even find them this way because `Enumerable.OfType` does not search recursively into child controls of a given control. You can try this recursive extension with `OfType`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> fnRecurse)
{
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        yield return item;

        IEnumerable<T> seqRecurse = fnRecurse(item);
        if (seqRecurse != null)
        {
            foreach (T itemRecurse in Traverse(seqRecurse, fnRecurse))
            {
                yield return itemRecurse;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in following way:

```
var allRadTextBoxes = this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
          .Traverse(c => c.Controls.OfType<RadTextBox>());
foreach(var radTextBox in allRadTextBoxes)
{
    radTextBox.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
}
```

Comment: Tim I'm getting the error: system.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.UI.Control>' does not contain a definition for 'Traverse'

Comment: @Mike, As this is an extension method you have to add a *using* for the namespace of the class containing this method

Comment: I feel dumb for going mind blank but can you show me an example of what you mean

Comment: Yes, it is an [**extension method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx). You need to put this method in a static class somewhere. This class must be accessible in the page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your control is not **directly on the page**. Your control is in a **Form** that is on the page.

```
foreach (var control in this.Page.Form.Controls.OfType<RadTextBox>())
    {
        control.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    }
```

You can either look for the Controls inside the form, or search recursively using *Tim Schmelter* approach